# invalid argument supplied for foreach() al generar url de imagen de minecraft

Tags: php

hace un tiempo me encontre este codigo php para poder generar la url de la imagen de minecraft y hasta ahora no me dio error

Mi problema esta en la linea:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
```

a la hora de ejecutarlo me tira el error:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

Imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no se como podria solucionarlo

Aquí dejo el código:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Username to UUID</title>
        <?php
        function getUUID($users,$agent) {
            $data = array();
            foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
                array_push($data, $value);
            }
            $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method' => 'post',
            'max_redirects' => '0',
            'ignore_errors' => '1'
                    )
                );

            
                    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);
```

Alguien me podria ayudar a solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias antemano!

Comment: Lee [ask]: el código va _como texto, con formato, **en la pregunta**_. Además, haz tu título más descriptivo, ej.: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() al generar url de imagen de minecraft"

Answer (score 0):

Usar `@` para suprimir posibles mensajes de error es una muy mala práctica y origen de problemas, como no saber exactamente dónde ocurre el error. Es mejor verificar que se están recibiendo datos adecuados o inicializando las variables con un valor por defecto.

Se puede hacer fácilmente con asignación ternaria

```
    <?php
    // Si usuarios proviene de $_GET se separa por coma
    // De lo contrario, se inicializa variable con arreglo vacío
    $users = (isset($_GET['uuiduser'])) ? explode(',', $_GET['uuiduser']) : [];

    // Si agente proviene de $_GET se asigna, de lo contrario, cadena vacía
    $agent = (isset($_GET['uuidagent'])) ? $_GET['uuidagent'] : '';
    
    // La comparación se hace con las variables creadas
    if (count($users) > 0 && $agent != '') {
        $data = getUUID($users, $agent);
        // La función json_decode() puede devolver NULL si algo falló
        if($data !== null) {
            foreach($data as $key => $value) {
                // **** Aquí muestras datos
            }
        }
    }
```

Dentro de la función no uses variables provenientes de $_GET, sino las que proporcionas por parámetro:

```
    function getUUID($users, $agent) {
        $data = array();
        foreach ($users as $key => $value) {
            array_push($data, $value);
        }
        $opts = array('http' =>
            array(
                'method' => 'post',
                'max_redirects' => '0',
                'ignore_errors' => '1'
            )
        );

        $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

        // Envía la variable $agent que recibiste como parámetro
        return json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/' . $agent, false, $context), true);
    }
```

Finalmente, estás recibiendo la variable `$users` y creas un arreglo `$data` que, al final, es exactamente igual al que recibiste, pero no lo usas. Entonces, necesitas revisar el código, entender lo que hace y analizar si realmente sirve para lo que quieres lograr.

Answer (score 0):

El error que se está presentando por si mismo describe el problema, pero dicho en otras palabras, indica que la variable `$data` no puede ser iterada por el foreach.

Dado que mencionas que no había fallado, te sugiero que revises en primer lugar la url donde recuperas la información, en este caso la de esta linea:

```
return json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/'.@$_GET['uuidagent'], false, $context),true);
```

Revisa que los parámetros que estás enviando sean los correctos `@$_GET['uuidagent']`, ya que ese parece ser el origen del problema.

También como sugerencia, almacena las variables antes de pasarlas en la url:

```
$uuidagent = $_GET['uuidagent']
```